# Why does mysql fulltext search ignore obvious?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using fulltext search in mysql (`string` column has `FULLTEXT`-index), but was really surprised how pretty obvious matches are sorted down, but not related are better rank or higher order:

```
mysql> SELECT r_nr,string,  MATCH( string ) AGAINST( 'Tuhat üks ööd' ) AS score FROM raamat.sonaotsing WHERE MATCH( string ) AGAINST( 'Tuhat üks ööd' ) LIMIT 10;
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| r_nr   | string                                                                  | score              |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  54815 | Tuhat üks ööd 1932 Noor Eesti                                           |  7.703660488128662 |
|  26844 | Tuhat üks ööd 2006 994940990x 9789949409907 Pegasus                     | 7.6198859214782715 |
|  83249 | Tuhat fakti Nõukogude Eestist 1976 Perioodika                           | 7.5379133224487305 |
|  32090 | Tuhat üks viirastust 1997 Alexandre Dumas Athena                        | 7.5379133224487305 |
|  11052 | Ja üks päev on lihtsalt tuhat ööd 2002 Ly Gunnaritütar 9985787765       | 7.5379133224487305 |
|  20826 | Tuhat üks ööd Valitud lugusid I II 1984 Eesti Raamat                    | 7.5379133224487305 |
|  38774 | Tuhat roosi 1995 Bethany Campbell Kuldsulg                              | 7.5379133224487305 |
|  50706 | Tuhat üks ööd Valitud lugusid 1984 1 osa Eesti Raamat                   | 7.5379133224487305 |
| 186004 | Tuhat üks ööd Hommikumaa muinasjutud 1911 O Rudolph J ja A Paalmann     | 7.5379133224487305 |
| 175832 | Jeesus toitis viis tuhat meest Loe ja värvi 1991 Ra                     |  7.457685470581055 |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I can't figure out why rows 3, 4, 5 and 7 have same match score as 6, 8 and 9. Line 3 contains only one word from my query, line 4 just 2 and 5th contains all 3 but in different order and not in sequence. For my understanding lines 1, 2, 6, 8 and 9 should be first 5 in matching, not particularly in this order.

Do I miss something obvious here?

Comment: I am not an expert of fulltext search algorithm, but just as a guess that could the string length and other characters (noise) not digits that push results out of top results.

Comment: @Alex: seems to me, that 6th and 8th row have much better noise/match ratio than for example 3rd or 5th row. And 10th row has almost same matching score but only one matched word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some way it was obvious: I had default configuration (for Myisam table) 4 for minimal word length, so both three-letter words ('üks' and 'ööd') were ignored.

After changing configration

```
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

I got much better result, but still some weird rows have better scores than simpler and with lower noise/match ratio. But this is another story.